# VBA, Query Vertica database and populate to excel

Tags: excel, vertica, squirrel-sql, vba

I  query a vertica database (using squirrel-sql tool). Is this possible to be done in excel and populate into a worksheet?
Does anyone have a possible solution for this?

Can't find anything about this online.
I have the driver location, host name, port name, user/pass.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. [Installing the Client Drivers on Windows](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/InstallingDrivers/Windows/InstallingTheClientDriversOnWindows.htm%3FTocPath%3DConnecting%2520to%2520Vertica%7CClient%2520Libraries%7CClient%2520Drivers%7CInstalling%2520the%2520Client%2520Drivers%2520and%2520Tools%2520on%2520Windows%7C_____0), 2. [Testing an ODBC DSN Using Excel](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/TestingADSNUsingExcel.htm), 3. [Client Drivers](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query Vertica directly from [excel](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/TestingADSNUsingExcel.htm). I did it and it works, just download ODBC driver, install driver, setup DNS and follow to instructions.

For version 7.x, read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientODBC/TestingADSNUsingExcel2007.htm)

### UPDATE on comment

Full documentation: [Installing the Client Drivers and Tools on Windows](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/InstallingDrivers/Windows/InstallingTheClientDriversOnWindows.htm%3FTocPath%3DConnecting%2520to%2520Vertica%7CClient%2520Libraries%7CClient%2520Drivers%7CInstalling%2520the%2520Client%2520Drivers%2520and%2520Tools%2520on%2520Windows%7C_____0)

1. Download Windows Client Drivers from [here](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/). Excel require ODBC drivers.
2. Install drivers(double click on `exe` file -> `next` -> `next` -> profit!!).
3. Set up ODBC DNS, instructions are [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/SettingUpADSN.htm)
4. Follow to instructions [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/TestingADSNUsingExcel.htm)
5. profit!

Comment: Do you know where the driver is supposed to be located? I cant find the vertica driver in step c. Im guessing I need to add it to a folder.

Comment: You need to download them and install. You can download drivers from [Vertica Portal](https://my.vertica.com/) or from [Vertica Marketplace](https://marketplace.microfocus.com/vertica/search?q=ODBC).

Comment: read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/SettingUpADSN.htm) how to setup an ODBC DSN.

Comment: thanks, I already have the vertica driver jar file, but I just need to be able to see this in the data sources area. My question is, where do I put this jar file so I can see it when creating a new data source?  I am  unable to download vertica drivers on company laptop. So I have a jar file already.

Comment: `jar` - its JDBC drivers(Java) and not ODBC(Excel require ODBC/ADO drivers). You need to download and install `Client Drivers and Tools for Windows`, its an `exe` file, read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/InstallingDrivers/Windows/InstallingVerticaClientDriverOnWindows.htm).